# In Angular reactive form how to send the unchecked data of form to api to delete it from table

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form where user  can check multiple values and on click of save all the data saves to database.
Next time when user uncheck few values, I want to send those as well along with checked values to update my database (delete the unchecked values and add if any new checked values are there).
I am using angular 12 reactive form with spring boot and oracle db.

Comment: provide code. This does not make much sense.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.